# Galaxy fit stuck at boot screen

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, reboot, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-fit

My galaxy fit became unresponsive after the phone memory got full, so I removed the battery and replaced it back. Now my phone is stuck on the booting screen, it just shows the glowing samsung text and then reboots.
I have also tried to to remove the sd card and reboot but it does not help

Comment: Have you tried clearing the userdata?

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: I'll post as an answer when I get to my computer, hang on.

Comment: I wouldn't start with that, though -- you would lose all your data (if Liam is talking about a "full clear" aka "factory reset"). You could try booting into "safe mode" and free some space instead. If that's what Liam has in mind: Yepp, good start. Walk through your apps' list and clear all their caches. Of course this depends on the fact you can at least get it booting completely into safe mode...

Comment: @Izzy how do I boot into safe mode ?

Comment: Liam already included that with his answer. The "key combination" to enter *safe mode* differs between devices and Android versions (see e.g. the Youtube video [How To Enable Safe Mode On Android](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_wuJxhWw_s)). For the Fit, [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1284813) says "Middle button + Power button" for 2.3 Gingerbread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to boot into safe mode:**

*Note: Not all devices support safe mode*

While your device is booting up, hold down the Home button. This should be done right after the screen starts up, before the boot animation does, and should be held until the device fully boots. Once done, you should see the words 'Safe Mode' in the bottom left corner.

**How to Factory Reset/Clear Userdata**

If booting into safe mode didn't work, or your device is still boot looping after removing some of the apps that are using the greatest memory, you will have to erase your data.

You should be able to access stock recovery by holding down the Volume UP button, the Home Buton and the Power button until the device finishes booting into recovery mode. From here you can use the volume keys to navigate to the wipe userdata option, and press the power button to select it. Once done, press the back key to go to the main menu and select to reboot the device now.

*This will erase **all** userdata on the device!*

**If it still doesn't work?**

If it still doesn't work after following these steps, then you will have to take it to a repair center, sorry!

Comment: I eventually had to do a factory reset, but home+power button was required to enter factory reset mode